# Does next() eliminate values from a generator?

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, generator

I've written a generator that does nothing more or less than store a range from 0 to 10:

```
result = (num for num in range(11))
```

When I want to print values, I can use `next()`:

```
print(next(result))
[Out]: 0
print(next(result))
[Out]: 1
print(next(result))
[Out]: 2
print(next(result))
[Out]: 3
print(next(result))
[Out]: 4
```

If I then run a `for` loop on the generator, it runs on the values that I have not called `next()` on:

```
for value in result:
    print(value)
[Out]: 5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Has the generator eliminated the other values by acting on them with a `next()` function? I've tried to find some documentation on the functionality of `next()` and generators but haven't been successful.

Comment: Yes. A generator is basically a function with state. Anytime you pull values from a generator, either trough `next`, iteration, etc., you are consuming those elements.

Comment: It doesn't remove a value; it simply doesn't *save* the value or provide any access to the sequence other than moving through it in one direction.

Comment: (Or I should say, it doesn't directly expose any previous values. `cycle(f)`, for example, is an iterator that caches every element seen in `f` so that the values can be repeated *ad infinitum* after the first trip through `f` is finished.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is can be implicitly deduced  from `next`'s [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) and by understanding the [`iterator` protocol/contract](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types):

> next(iterator[, default])
> Retrieve the next item from the iterator by
> calling its **next**() method. If default is given, it is returned if
> the iterator is exhausted, otherwise `StopIteration` is raised.

**Yes**. Using a generator's `__next__` method retrieves **and removes** the next value from the generator.

Comment: ....yes, if it ever stored the yielded value in the first place. The OP's exampe with `range` is a generator that iirc does not store the sequence of numbers it generates. Makes it fast over very large ranges, for one thing.

Comment: @mrblewog well `range` is not even an iterator (it does not implement `__next__`, and calling `next(range_obj)` raises a `TypeError`) so it's irrelevant. OP arbitrarily built a generator from a range object. They could have used anything else for the sake of the question

Comment: Right, `range` is *iterable*, and `iter(range(5))` would return a value of type `range_iterator`, which is probably semantically equivalent to the generator expression in the original question. (It's faster, too, with one less layer of the iterator protocol to dig through.)

Comment: @chepner interesting point. What did you mean by "faster"? "faster" than what?

Comment: Faster than `(num for num in range(5))`. The reason the generator expression works is that it first implicitly calls `iter` to get a `range_iteartor` for the `range` object, so that its `next` method really doesn't do anything except call `range_iterator.next`. A generator expression adds overhead to using another iterator which is only justified if you do some processing on the iteration. (For example, yielding a computed value based on the wrapped iterator, or filtering values based on some predicate.)

Answer (score 2):

tldr; yes

An iterator is essentially a value producer that yields successive values from its associated iterable object. The built-in function `next()` is used to obtain the next value from in iterator.
Here is an example using the same list as above:

```
>>> l = ['Sarah', 'Roark']
>>> itr = iter(l)
>>> itr
<list_iterator object at 0x100ba8950>
>>> next(itr)
'Sarah'
>>> next(itr)
'Roark'
>>> next(itr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

In this example, `l` is an iterable list and `itr` is the associated iterator, obtained with iter(). Each `next(itr)` call obtains the next value from `itr`.

Notice how an iterator retains its state internally. It knows which values have been obtained already, so when you call `next()`, it knows what value to return next.

If all the values from an iterator have been returned already, a subsequent `next()` call raises a `StopIteration` exception. Any further attempts to obtain values from the iterator will fail.

We can only obtain values from an iterator in one direction. We can’t go backward. There is no `prev()` function. But we can define two independent iterators on the same iterable object:

```
>>> l
['Sarah', 'Roark', 30]
>>> itr1 = iter(l)
>>> itr2 = iter(l)
>>> next(itr1)
'Sarah'
>>> next(itr1)
'Roark'
>>> next(itr1)
30
>>> next(itr2)
'Sarah'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a for loop in Python just returns the next item from the iterator, the same way that `next()` does.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

> The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order returned by the iterator.

So you can think of a for loop like this:

```
for x in container:
    statement()
```

As (almost) equivalent to a `while` loop:

```
iterator = iter(container)
while True:
    x = next(iterator)
    if x is None:
        break
    statement()
```

If `container` is already an iterator, then `iter(container)` is `container`.

**Note:** Technically, a for loop is more like this:

```
iterator = iter(container)
while True:
    try:
        x = iterator.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    statement()
```